# response data showing in error part of jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, json

I am sending some data from jquery.ajax to aspx, parsing there and writing on response, but that data is coming in error part, I think some error is being occured which is not being shown, but the correct data is getting returned in error part. Code is below.

JQUERY

```
var json = "{'uname':'" + $("#uname").val() + "','pwd':'" + $("#pwd").val() + "'}";
        alert(json);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "DataProcess.aspx?Save=1",
            data: json,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            async: false,
            success: function (msg) {
                alert(msg);
            },
            error: function (msg) { alert("failed: " + msg.responseText); }
        });
```

DataProcess.aspx.cs

```
namespace Test
{
    public partial class DataProcess : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
                ProcessAjaxRequest();
        }
        private void ProcessAjaxRequest()
        {
            if (Request.ContentType.Contains("json") && Request.QueryString["Save"] != null)
                SaveMyData();
        }
        private void SaveMyData()
        {
            System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(Request.InputStream);
            string line = "";
            line = sr.ReadToEnd();
            JObject jo = JObject.Parse(line);
            Response.Write(line);
            Response.Write((string)jo["uname"]);
            Response.Write((string)jo["pwd"]);

        }
    }
}
```

So i am getting what ever the response is in the error part, what is wrong?

K i got the problem, above code is correct, Now my other doubt is, can i call a particular nonstatic method from this same aspx.cs, I mean when i tried something like this "DataProcess.aspx/Test?Save=1". It gives error saying not a web method, I declared method as

```
[WebMethod]
public void Test(){
}
```

K guys, I thought the problem was gone, just now i observed that, if i write a string to response something like this Response.Write("success"), its comming in jquery error block, but when i write something like this "Response.Write(0);", its comming in success block. The first one should also come, someone explain whats the problem

Thanks

Comment: Can you paste an example of the "correct data"? And why are you using an AJAX call when `async` is set to `false`?

Comment: ajax url = `url: "Default.aspx/Login?Save=1",` page name = `DataProcess.aspx.cs`  ???

Comment: Try to debug your code from JObject jo = JObject.Parse(line); as I think either the parsing is failing or jo["uname"] would either be null or would give an Index out of bound expection.

Comment: by mistake i kept wrong url here, I corrected it now and also that is solves, but i added another question in the above one at bottom, please ans that. thanks for your replies. :)

Comment: You should use Web API for this task instead of using aspx as fake controller

Comment: can u provide a simple and good example please

Answer (score 0):

not sure the exact problem but your json looks like a string. it should be like this

```
var json = {'uname':'" + $("#uname").val() + "','pwd':'" + $("#pwd").val() + "'};
```

Comment: No, my jason is correct and output also, I have other doubt which i asked at the end of question, please answer that.  regards

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you have already figured out about [PageMethods](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/) (i.e. a static method decorated with `WebMethod` keyword).
Regarding your later question, its **not possible** to use non-static (instance) methods as Page Methods. The reason is quite simple - an instance method could access instance variables including control tree. Without view-state, ASP.NET cannot guarantee a correct control tree state in post-back scenarios. For such needs, `UpdatePanel` is the way to go - as it provides AJAX within the ASP.NET control model. Page Methods are meant for stream-lined communication where request/response data are minimalistic without overheads (i.e. the only meaningful data that you wants to communicate between client/server).